# Printing a nested key pair in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, serialization

I am sending a request to an API and the request is in JSON. I am able to save the request to a file and print the output, but I want to be able to print a nested key pair from the JSON file and not the entire thing.

Tried the following to print the nested pair.

```
nested_keys = ["eta", "arrT"]  
current_data = json_data



for keyValue in nested_keys:
    if keyValue in current_data:
        current_data = current_data[keyValue]
    else:
        print("Key not found in JSON data")
        break
else:
    print(current_data)
```

Comment: _Tried the following_ And what was the result?

Comment: This looks like a data problem, not a code problem.  You'll need to show us the full value of `json_data`.

Comment: @Swifty umm, what?  That's not a flaw at all.  He clearly **wants** to overwrite `current_data`, so it ends up as the nested item.  The full original data is still preserved in `json_data`.

Comment: I am very new to programming so thank you for the assistance. @JohnGordon, I get the 'key not found in JSON data'. I've set 'json_data = response.json()'. If I change the nested_keys to only include the top level key it still will not print and give an error.

Comment: You need to show us the **actual contents** of `json_data`.  Telling us that it came from `response.json()` is meaningless.

Comment: @Swifty If the original data has a top-level key `eta` that contains a subdictionary with the key `arrT` (i.e. something like `{"eta": {"arrT": "something"}}`), then both keys **will** be used.  Why do you say only the first key would be used?

Comment: @JohnGordon: oh, that's right; I didn't think of this situation.